# Combine multiple rows into one (complex)

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I have a rather large spreadsheet that I need to merge (probably using xlookup) with another, but first, I'd like to clean this one up.

The number of rows for each entry varies (from 1 to 3 or maybe 4) and the positioning of the values in each column is also variable.

I'd like to consolidate these rows for each unique entry (leftmost column) into one. The data includes both text and numbers.
The second column is just a repeat of the first without the duplicates. Either one can be removed or used based on convenience.

I updated my data to include the letters, but I get an error when linking to imgur.

[image: Example Data]

Comment: So.... what's the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A `sumifs()` might do it, but I don;t know what you would do if there were multiple values at column/row intersections, maybe `maxifs()` or similar alternative? You will also have to figure out how to navigate the differences in your combined first two columns (if they are meant to be different).

Comment: Do you want to fill all cells?

Answer (score 1):

This solution involves using FILTER function which is only available in O365 or Office 2021. Since you have only tagged Excel, most likely this solution is not for you.

See the below screenshot.

In K2 & L2

```
=UNIQUE(B2:B11)
```

In M2

```
=FILTER(D$2:D$11,($B$2:$B$11=$K2)*(NOT(ISBLANK(D$2:D$11))))
```

Drag it along and across the table.

[image]

This is of course based on assumption that only one cell per vertical block of cells for an Entry is filled and others are blank. If this is not true this solution will Spill the data and fail.

---

Edit 1

Modification based on below comment.

Use TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(D$2:D$11,($B$2:$B$11=$K2)*(NOT(ISBLANK(D$2:D$11)))))
```

See below screenshot. Refer Entry3

[image]

In fact, this formula can now simply be created as.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(D$2:D$11,$B$2:$B$11=$K2))
```

TEXTJOIN will automatically take care of blanks if any.

Comment: I do have 365, in fact.  Edited the tag. Thank you so much! Now, what if I had more than one entry in a column for the same Entry (Entry1, e.g.)? How would I concatenate those two pieces of text into one cell so that I don't lose data?

Comment: @tensor9 See Edit 1 in above answer. Hope it helps.